# scanf cannot take in input

Tags: c++, scanf

I am writing a program which read a file. But I find it cannot work well. Everytime it read at most 4 times then it stuck at scanf, and cannot input anymore. Hope someone can help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct user {
    char name[100];
    int rank;
};
user arr[500000];
void swap(int a, int b) {
    char tmp_name[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        tmp_name[i] = arr[a].name[i];
    }
    int tmp_rank = arr[a].rank;
    arr[a].rank = arr[b].rank;
    arr[b].rank = tmp_rank;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        arr[a].name[i] = arr[b].name[i];
        arr[b].name[i] = tmp_name[i];
    }
}
int main() {
    int l = 0;
    int r = 499999;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf("%d %s %d %d", arr[i].name, &arr[i].rank);
    }
    int ran = rand();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (ran % 2 == 0) {
            printf("0 ");
            unsigned int num = rand();
            num = num % (r - l + 1) + l;
            printf("%s %d\n", arr[num].name, arr[num].rank);
            swap(l, num);
            l++;
        } else {
            printf("1 ");
            unsigned int num = rand();
            printf("%s\n", arr[num % 500000].name);
        }
    }
    printf("2\n");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %s %d %d", arr[i].name, &arr[i].rank);` With 4 format codes I would expect to also have 4 variables to store the values into.

Comment: As per the structure members this `scanf("%d %s %d %d", arr[i].name, &arr[i].rank);` shall be `scanf("%s%d", arr[i].name, &arr[i].rank);` As you have provided more and incorrect format specifier.

Comment: Turn warnings on: most compilers will immediately warn about the wrong `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
scanf("%d %s %d %d", arr[i].name, &arr[i].rank);
```

use this:

```
scanf("%s %d ", arr[i].name, &arr[i].rank);
```

As you are taking only 2 inputs one is `arr[i].name` which is a string for which you will be using `%s`, and the other input is `arr[i].rank` which is a integer for which you will be using `%d`.